# python - iterating over each digit in number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like this:

```
['0', '2757', '2757']
```

When I run this:

```
for i in results[1]:
    print i
```

it's return 4 lines

```
2
7
5
7
```

I only want it to return the number `2757`

Comment: What is you target output. If you wan to print `2757` just do `print result[1]`

Comment: when you run `for i in results[1]`, you're telling the Python interpreter to iterate individually over each part of the string location at `results[1]`.  Instead of iterating, you just need to print the index - like the answers say!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "return" you mean "print". You don't need a loop. Just print the element directly.

```
>>> seq = ['0', '2757', '2757']
>>> print seq[1]
2757
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop is specific to the second value in the list so i represents each character of the element in this loop. You can just print the second item of the list

```
    >>> list = ['0', '2757', '2757']
    >>> print list[1]
    2757
```

or if you want to run a loop that returns each item you have to make it non specific to the second item in the list

```
    >>> for i in list:
    ...     print i

    0
    2757
    2757
```